# fetch chromium doesn't work

Tags: git, chromium

fetch chromium --nosvn=True instruction makes error below:

```
`C:\Users\Gunwoo\workspace\chromium>fetch chromium --nosvn=True
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
Running: svn ls --non-interactive svn://svn.chromium.org/chrome
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 253, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "E:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 249, in main
    return run(dryrun, spec, root)
  File "E:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 243, in run
    return checkout.init()
  File "E:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 108, in init
    self.run_svn('ls', '--non-interactive', svn_spec['svn_url'])
  File "E:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 83, in run_svn
    return subprocess.check_call(('svn',) + cmd, **kwargs)
  File "E:\depot_tools\python_bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 457, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "E:\depot_tools\python_bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 444, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "E:\depot_tools\python_bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "E:\depot_tools\python_bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 804, in _execute_child startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2]`
```

> I installed depot_tools and included its PATH into system environment
>   variable.

What should I do?

Comment: and My OS is Windows 8. plz help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run into the same problem on my windows machine with 'git status' showing bunch of files in depot_tools as modified. 
Possible you have unstaged changes in depot_tools. 
My solve git reset --hard HEAD no depot_tools folder.